# Is it possible to limit number of executing jobs per group?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I've got `2` groups. Each group has `10` jobs that can be executed at the same time. `ThreadPool` allows `10` threads at the same time. I want to have `5` jobs of group 1 and `5` jobs of group 2 to be executed at the same time (not `10`-`0`, `2`-`8`).  How can I limit first and second groups to have max `5` jobs executing at the same time?

Comment: Why you can't create two `org.quartz.Scheduler` instances?

Comment: this may be appropriate solution for me... I don't know yet. Is it possible to solve it by using single Quartz Scheduler?